# Verifying a source that lacks a citation

Tags: reference-request, integration, citations

In this [German Mathematics Wikibook](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Bestimmte_Integrale:_Form_R(x,sin)) page, formula $0.5$ lists the following equation
$$\int_0^1 \sin(\pi x) x^x (1-x)^{1-x} \ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi e}{24}$$ as supposedly attributed to Ramanujan (Google translate gives "formula by Ramanujan"). However, the page lacks a citation section, which is absolutely unfortunate, so I'm not certain whether to trust this source or not. How would I be able to verify the source is correct?

A quick Google search only returned the above the page, so no promising results. I have thought about contacting Dr. Bruce C. Berndt, the expert on Ramanujan's mathematical career, though I'd like to know what other alternatives are available. Thank you!

Comment: Did you ask Tobias Pfanner (the author of the Wikibooks page)?

Comment: I am not familiar with him. Where would I be able to find his contact information? I would assume he would also be an administrator of the site listed above, though I am not finding his name.

Comment: Math.SE: [Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}\sin{(\pi x)}x^x(1-x)^{1-x}\,dx =\frac{\pi e}{24} $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958624/prove-that-int-01-sin-pi-xxx1-x1-x-dx-frac-pi-e24). BTW it was the first result when I searched for [frac pi e 24 integral](https://www.google.com/search?q=frac+pi+e+24+integral) in Google.

Comment: Each Mediawiki page has an edit history (in German, it’s the link called “Versionsgeschichte”). There you can find what edits were done by what users; in this case, it’s pretty much a one-man job. Next to each user name, there is a link to their user talk page (“Diskussion”), here https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Benutzer_Diskussion:Tobias_Pfanner . You can ask a question there. However, the user seems not to have been active for some time, so it’s unclear whether that will work.

Comment: Just to clarify - since the page you linked has a proof of this result, you are probably not asking for a proof, but rather for a reference containing this result? If that's the case, you should probably use ([tag:reference-request]) tag. (And make this clear in the post.)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: I didn't know the existence of said tag. I just made the edit. Thank you.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek: Tobias Pfanner's last login is May 6th, 2015, so I'm not sure this approach would work.

Comment: Another MSE link: [Two curious “identities” on $x^x, e,$ and $\pi$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242587/two-curious-identities-on-xx-e-and-pi).(strange that it is not linked to the other MSE question). Unfortunately, there, too, the German site is  the only source.

Comment: @nospoon For now, I have left a message to Tobias Pfanner and to Dr. Bruce C. Berndt. Hopefully, I look forward to a response from either of them.